# Navbar no lista correctamente en tamaño móvil cuando lo subo al servidor

Tags: bootstrap, menú

Mi diseño en forma local se ve como la imagen a la izquierda, pero cuando lo subo a la página aparece con un margen blanco a los lados y la lista del navbar se ve horizontal y no vertical como se ve a mano derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El código está aquí:
https://github.com/dalvarez131/heyyeahpixel

Adjunto todo el codigo, el navbar está incluido en la clase `normal_header` del primer div después del body, por favor notar también las librerías que estoy usando no se si por allí puede estar el problema.

Gracias.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.title{
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: darkorange;

}
.title a:link{
  color: darkorange;
}
.title a:visited{
  color: darkorange;
}
.title a:hover{
  color: darkorange;
}
.title a:active{
  color: darkorange;
}



#menud{
  color: darkorange;
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 16px;

}
.container-fluid{
  width: 95%;
}
.inicio{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#exampleInputAmount{
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 50%;
}
.container{
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 0px;

}
.clasificacion{
  padding-left:30px;
}
.form-control{
  width: 30%;
}
.product-box__item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.product-box__item p{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 15px;

}
.caption{
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.final {
  background-color: Snow;
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.final p{

  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}
.final1 {
  display: none;
}
#exampleInputAmount{
  width: 30%;
}

#barra {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#barra2{
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
.product-box__item .thumbnail {
  min-height: 400px;
}

@media (min-width: 651px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #barra{
    display: none;
  }
  .raya{
    display: none;
  }
  #exampleInputAmount{
    display: none;
  }
  #exampleInputAmount1{
    display: none;
  }

}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #barra{
    display: none;
  }
  .raya{
    display: none;
  }
  #exampleInputAmount{
    display: none;
  }
  #exampleInputAmount1{
    display: none;
  }
  #left {
    padding-right: 20%;
    padding-left: 20%;
  }
  .todas {
    display: none;

  }
  .final{
    display: none;
  }
  .final1 {
    display: inline;

  }
  .final1 {
    background-color: Snow;
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left:  0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 0px;
  }
  .final1 p{

    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>HeyYeahPixel</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/logo.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:400,700i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="tools/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="normal_header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid inicio">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-toggler title" style="font-size:36px" href="#">HeyYeahPixel</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <input type="text" class="form form-inline" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Busca articulos">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="exampleInputAmount1">Buscar</button>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a id="menud" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>Canasta</a></li>
            <li><a id="menud" href="#">Registrarse</a></li>
            <li><a id="menud" href="#">Entrar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="barra">
      <div class="container">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="barra2" data-toggle="dropdown">VideoGames</b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Metroid</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Super Mario</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Megaman</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kirby</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Space Invaders</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Horda - Wow</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Otros</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="barra2" data-toggle="dropdown">Marvel</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Ironman</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deadpool</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Otros</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </div><!--  end navbar -->
<hr class="raya"/>

  <div class="container cuerpo">
    <h5><small>Inicio (Articulos)</small></h5>
    <h4 class="todas"><strong>Todas las Categorías</strong></h4>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="left">
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="line-height:0px">
        <div class="panel-body"><strong>Todas las categorias</strong></div>
        <div class="panel-body clasificacion">VideoGames</div>
        <div class="panel-body clasificacion">Marvel</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
      <div class="row product-box" id="products">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product-box__item">
            <div class="rounded">
              <img src="./images/videogames.jpg" alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
                <p><strong>VideoGames</strong></p>
                <p>Metroid</p>
                <p>Super Mario</p>
                <p>Megaman</p>
                <p>Kirby</p>
                <p>Space Invaders</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product-box__item">
            <div class="rounded">
              <img src="./images/marvel.jpg" alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
                <p><strong>Marvel</strong></p>
                <p>Ironman</p>
                <p>Deadpool</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr width=100% class="final"/>


  <div class="final">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <p><strong>Únete a la comunidad</strong></p>
      <p>Grupos</p>
      <p>Foros</p>
      <p>Próximos eventos</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <p><strong>Descubre y compra</strong></p>
      <p>Blog</p>
      <p>Buscar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <p><strong>Conócenos</strong></p>
      <p>Presentación</p>
      <p>Políticas</p>
      <p>Desarrolladores</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <p><strong>Siguenos</strong></p>
      <p><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Facebook</a></p>
      <p><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Pinterest</a></p>
      <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/heyyeahpixel/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Instagram</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="final1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <p><strong>Siguenos</strong></p>
      <p><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Facebook</a></p>
      <p><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Pinterest</a></p>
      <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/heyyeahpixel/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Instagram</a></p>

    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Diana, el enlace del código no funciona, pero antes que arreglarlo, preferimos que pongas la parte relevante aquí, en la pregunta, haciendo clic en el botón editar.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. No olvides usar los acentos en tu próxima pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Es raro, parece que algunos estilos no se estén aplicando o que algo los sobreescriba. ¿En local y en el servidor es todo exactamente igual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abriendo el inspector de elementos veo que se le aplica un `padding-left` y `padding-right` de `20px` dentro de `@media (max-width: 767px)`, esta condición se encuentra en el archivo `https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css`.

Lo que puedes hacer para sobrescribir esa condición seria colocar una nueva regla marcada como `!important` esta regla la puedes colocar antes del cierre del `head`

```
body {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Ahora para que el menú quede ordenado en forma de listado, el mismo archivo mencionado arriba realiza cambios no deseados, solo hay que sobre escribir la regla únicamente para los dispositivos móviles por lo tanto agregaremos media queries, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* establecemos que solo se aplicara para dispositivos móviles */
  .navbar .nav > li {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Te dejo tu ejemplo con los cambios realizados

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: darkorange;
}

.title a:link {
  color: darkorange;
}

.title a:visited {
  color: darkorange;
}

.title a:hover {
  color: darkorange;
}

.title a:active {
  color: darkorange;
}

#menud {
  color: darkorange;
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 95%;
}

.inicio {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#exampleInputAmount {
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.clasificacion {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.form-control {
  width: 30%;
}

.product-box__item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.product-box__item p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.caption {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.final {
  background-color: Snow;
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.final p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.final1 {
  display: none;
}

#exampleInputAmount {
  width: 30%;
}

#barra {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#barra2 {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.product-box__item .thumbnail {
  min-height: 400px;
}

@media (min-width: 651px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #barra {
    display: none;
  }
  .raya {
    display: none;
  }
  #exampleInputAmount {
    display: none;
  }
  #exampleInputAmount1 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #barra {
    display: none;
  }
  .raya {
    display: none;
  }
  #exampleInputAmount {
    display: none;
  }
  #exampleInputAmount1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #left {
    padding-right: 20%;
    padding-left: 20%;
  }
  .todas {
    display: none;
  }
  .final {
    display: none;
  }
  .final1 {
    display: inline;
  }
  .final1 {
    background-color: Snow;
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 0px;
  }
  .final1 p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>HeyYeahPixel</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/logo.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:400,700i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="tools/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      padding-left: 0px !important;
      padding-right: 0px !important;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .navbar .nav>li {
        float: none;
      }
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="normal_header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid inicio">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-toggler title" style="font-size:36px" href="#">HeyYeahPixel</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <input type="text" class="form form-inline" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Busca articulos">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="exampleInputAmount1">Buscar</button>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a id="menud" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>Canasta</a></li>
            <li><a id="menud" href="#">Registrarse</a></li>
            <li><a id="menud" href="#">Entrar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="barra">
    <div class="container">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="barra2" data-toggle="dropdown">VideoGames</b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Metroid</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Super Mario</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Megaman</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kirby</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Space Invaders</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Horda - Wow</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Otros</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="barra2" data-toggle="dropdown">Marvel</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Ironman</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Deadpool</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Otros</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </div>
  <!--  end navbar -->
  <hr class="raya" />

  <div class="container cuerpo">
    <h5><small>Inicio (Articulos)</small></h5>
    <h4 class="todas"><strong>Todas las Categorías</strong></h4>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="left">
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="line-height:0px">
        <div class="panel-body"><strong>Todas las categorias</strong></div>
        <div class="panel-body clasificacion">VideoGames</div>
        <div class="panel-body clasificacion">Marvel</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
      <div class="row product-box" id="products">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product-box__item">
          <div class="rounded">
            <img src="./images/videogames.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="caption">
              <p><strong>VideoGames</strong></p>
              <p>Metroid</p>
              <p>Super Mario</p>
              <p>Megaman</p>
              <p>Kirby</p>
              <p>Space Invaders</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product-box__item">
          <div class="rounded">
            <img src="./images/marvel.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="caption">
              <p><strong>Marvel</strong></p>
              <p>Ironman</p>
              <p>Deadpool</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr width=100% class="final" />


  <div class="final">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <p><strong>Únete a la comunidad</strong></p>
      <p>Grupos</p>
      <p>Foros</p>
      <p>Próximos eventos</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <p><strong>Descubre y compra</strong></p>
      <p>Blog</p>
      <p>Buscar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <p><strong>Conócenos</strong></p>
      <p>Presentación</p>
      <p>Políticas</p>
      <p>Desarrolladores</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <p><strong>Siguenos</strong></p>
      <p><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Facebook</a></p>
      <p><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Pinterest</a></p>
      <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/heyyeahpixel/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Instagram</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="final1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <p><strong>Siguenos</strong></p>
      <p><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Facebook</a></p>
      <p><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Pinterest</a></p>
      <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/heyyeahpixel/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Instagram</a></p>

    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tengo un solo inconveniente con                                   .navbar .nav>li {
      float: none;
 }     y es que en tamaño diferente a movil continua apareciendo vertical cuando alli si debe aparecer horizontal, podrias ayudarme por favor? te agradezco mucho

Comment: @DianaPatriciaAlvarezRamos he arreglado el problema, debería tener la funcionalidad que corresponde

Comment: Muchas gracias, si ya funciona bien :) ten un gran dia!!!

Comment: @DianaPatriciaAlvarezRamos si te ha servido la respuesta no dudes en votarla (tener al menos 15 de reputación), si consideras que la respuesta resolvió tus dudas o problemas no dudes en aceptar la respuesta.